# How do I install XamlPad?

Tags: .net, wpf, xamlpad

This is going to sound silly, because everyone seems to take it for granted that XamlPad is just *there,* including the [MSDN article about XamlPad](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742398.aspx).

But I've installed Visual Studio 2008, which AFAIK installs the .NET 3.5 SDK (how could it not?), which is supposed to include XamlPad. But there is no XamlPad.exe in my Start Menu or anywhere on my PC. I've even done a `dir /s xamlpad.exe` from the command line, to make sure the problem isn't with the Windows Indexing Service not seeing what's in front of its face like usual. No dice.

I'd like to demo some XAML to my co-workers, but I don't want to use the godawful XAML designer in Visual Studio if I can help it. How do I get a copy of XamlPad to install onto my PC?

I'm running Vista 64-bit if that makes any difference (it shouldn't, but you never can tell).

Comment: These days, [Visual Studio XAML Designer and Blend for Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn904477.aspx) seem to be the standard tools for XAML authoring.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

At the bottom of the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742398.aspx) page there's this comment:

> The Start Menu shortcut is not
>   installed by VS2008
>
> The program binary is installed
>   however in Program Files\Microsoft
>   SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin

I've just checked on my machine and it's there.

For newer versions of Windows and Visual Studio the SDK version will be 7 or 8. The latest on my machine (Windows 8 with Visual Studio 2013) is `v8.1A` and it's in `Program Files (x86)` on 64 bit versions of the OS. So you will need to look in:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows

and see which version you have installed.

There's also a link on that MSDN page to the new version on the author's blog.

Comment: So it is! I don't know how I missed it. For reference, that path is correct even on a 64-bit system -- it is installed to the 64-bit "Program Files", not to the 32-bit "Program Files (x86)" like most apps are.

Comment: There is no `V6.0A` in `Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows`

Comment: @gyozokudor - the answer was written in 2009 when there was. The version of the SDK is now (2015) v8.1A!

Comment: In SDK 7.0 and newer, that file does not seem to exist anymore. (I tried downloading XamlPadX, from the answer below, and that's been working ok so far).

Comment: @peterflynn. Well it is nearly 8 years on from when I posted this answer!

Answer (score 10):

[Kaxaml](http://www.kaxaml.com/) is a good alternative for XAMLPad, or even a good replacement for it.

Answer (score 7):

Try [XamlPadX](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/llobo/tag/XamlPadX/). The latest version is [XamlPadX4.0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/llobo/2008/08/25/xamlpadx-4-0/).

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, both XamlpadX and Kaxaml do not support events (where would be the handler?) or class references (there is no code-behind).

You may be missing the purpose of these editors - they are very useful when dealing with 'pure' xaml - figuring out styles, templates and the like, outside of a large project / solution. Once complete to your satisfaction you incorporate your XAML back into the project.